# Jquery Ajax replace DIV in first time but not in second time(MVC4)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

**View**

```
@section Scripts{
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#UserSearch').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.href,
                        cache:false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {id:$('#SearchName').val()},                    
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#ajaxsample').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    }

    <table>
    <tr>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="SearchName"/>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a id="UserSearch" href='@Url.Action("Contribute", "Project")'>Search</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="ajaxsample">
            T_T
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contribute(String id)
        {
                String UserName = id;
                PMSDBContext PMP = new PMSDBContext();
                List<_ContributeViewModel> result = new List<_ContributeViewModel>();

                result = PMP.Users
                             .Join(PMP.Friendships, u => u.UserID,
                             f => f.FriendID,
                             (u, f) => new { u, f })
                             .Where(m => m.f.UserID == 1 && m.u.Name.Contains(UserName) && m.f.Status == 1)
                             .Select(s => new _ContributeViewModel
                             {
                                 UserID = s.u.UserID,
                                 PhoneNo=s.u.PhoneNo,
                                 Facebook=s.u.Facebook,
                                 Name=s.u.Name
                             }
                             ).ToList();

            return View("UserSearch",result);
        }
```

**UserSearch View**

```
@model List<PMS.View_Model._ContributeViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchResult";
}
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>
            <u>Search Result</u>
        </th>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>PhoneNo</th>
        <th>FaceBook</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(model => model.UserID != null))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PhoneNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Facebook)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

When I first click Search button with some text in `textbox`,`UserSearch View` replace `"T_T"` with database results but second time page reloaded and `"T_T"` replace UserSearch View and third time User Search View replace `"T_T"` again and  that happens continuously...Question is what can I do `UserSearch View` to replace `"T_T"` in every click?

Comment: What you mean by second time?How is page reloded? it is an ajax call so page wont be reloaded right?

Comment: what did you expect ??

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe dont know sir...first time click replace T_T with view but second time,the whole page reloaded and back to T_T..

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I expect to replace T_T with view in every click sir

Comment: can you put your UserSearch view

Comment: did you get any javascript error ?

Comment: then where did you place your div and all ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV no sir..breakpoints show that [HttpPost] and [HttpGet] happens alternatively in each click

Comment: no need to call me sir , i am also beginner in  mvc

Comment: what did you want to display into your div ? is it the result list ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
$('#UserSearch').click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: '/Project/Contribute',
         dataType:'html',
         type: 'POST',
         data: { id:$('#SearchName').val() },                    
         success: function (result) {
           $('#ajaxsample').html(result);
         }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Your Action Will be

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Contribute(String id)
{
     //Your logic. .....
     return PartialView("UserSearch",result);
}
```

Normally it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning complete view you can use tagbuilder to construct the html markup and send that

```
[HttpPost]
public MvcHtmlString Contribute(String id)
{
   String UserName = id;
   PMSDBContext PMP = new PMSDBContext();
   List<_ContributeViewModel> result = new List<_ContributeViewModel>();
   result = PMP.Users
               .Join(PMP.Friendships, u => u.UserID,
                                 f => f.FriendID,
                                 (u, f) => new { u, f })
                                 .Where(m => m.f.UserID == 1 && m.u.Name.Contains(UserName) && m.f.Status == 1)
                                 .Select(s => new _ContributeViewModel
                                 {
                                     UserID = s.u.UserID,
                                     PhoneNo=s.u.PhoneNo,
                                     Facebook=s.u.Facebook,
                                     Name=s.u.Name
                                     }
                                     ).ToList();

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    TagBuilder ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");
    foreach (var item in result )
    {

                output.Append(ulTag.ToString());
                ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");

     }
     output.Append(ulTag.ToString();
     return output.ToString();
}
```

I think the problem you are facing is due to an entire page being rendered and problems with its replacement in the div.

Comment: is it returning ul tags?